# When should I create a new object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use this package [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js) to send email. First I need to create a new instance of `mailgun` then use it to send email, this is a simple version of my code:

```
const mgInstance = mailgun({
  apiKey: '...',
  domain: '...',
});

function sendMail1() {
  mgInstance.messages().send(/* ... */);
}

function sendMail2() {
  mgInstance.messages().send(/* ... */);
}
```

This code works fine. I just wonder if I move the code used to create new `mailgun` instance inside each functions, like this:

```
function sendMail1() {
  const mgInstance = mailgun({
    apiKey: '...',
    domain: '...',
  });

  mgInstance.messages().send(/* ... */);
}

function sendMail2() {
  const mgInstance = mailgun({
    apiKey: '...',
    domain: '...',
  });

  mgInstance.messages().send(/* ... */);
}
```

My question is: are there any differences between these implementation? is there a better one between them?

Comment: Is this question about coding patterns or more about mailgun in particular?

Comment: If the API Key and domain is the same and only the address and message changes, I would expect to see ONE function

Comment: @MaxArt it is about coding patterns

Comment: That depends: if your mailgun instance does not take up much memory and needs some time to initialize, I would create one instance and re-use it over the application's lifecycle. If it is large and fast, I'd recreate every time I need it, so it gets destroyed once it leaves its containing function.

Comment: @mplungjan  API Key and domain is the same

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `mailgun` factory function is lightweight enough, I would use a wrapper factory:

```
function getMailerInstance() {
  return mailgun({
    apiKey: '...',
    domain: '...'
  });
}

function sendMail1() {
  const mgInstance = getMailerInstance();

  mgInstance.messages().send(/* ... */);
}
```

This way, you can also easily switch to a singleton pattern, or do other computational logic before calling `mailgun` and so on.

I would also create a generic `sendMail` function that deals with... well, sending mails, and let other functions call that instead of using Mailgun's API directly. So, if you need to switch your mail API, you just need to change a small portion of your code (namely, `getMailerInstance` and `sendMail`).

Also notice how I used the generic name `getMailerInstance` instead of `getMGInstance`, which binds your code to Mailgun.

As a plus, consider returning a Promise in `getMailerInstance`.